# How to get document from elastic search with partial query string?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have three documents indexed with title "manage", "manager", and "management".

I am searching by following query:

```
  query: {
    query_string: {
           "query": "manage*",
           "fields": ["title"],
     }
  }
}
```

I am getting same **score** for all three documents. I want document with `"title": "manage"` first, then manager and management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you want. The easiest one to try out is to resort to [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#_script_based_sorting) and return a score that matches the length of the data:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['title.keyword'].value.length()"
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "manage*",
      "fields": [
        "title"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note: if you don't have the `title.keyword` field, you can change your script to work from the source directly:

```
params._source['title'].length()
```

You'll get `manage` (with score of 6), then `manager` (with score of 7) and then `management` (with score of 10).

The other way to achieve this is to actually index another integer field (e.g. `titleLength`) with the actual length of the `title` field and sort by `titleLength`.

Answer (score 0):

**The query above searches all the documents containing `manage`, but here since boost is applied to `manage`, so the document containing `manage` will have a higher score as compared to other documents.**

To know more about Query String Query refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

**Index Data**

```
{ "name":"manage" }
{ "name":"manager"}
{ "name":"management"}
```

**Search Query**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "name"                     
      ],
      "query": "manage^2*"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 3.3263016,
            "_source": {
                "name": "manage"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "name": "manager"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "name": "management"
            }
        }
    ]
```

**Edit 1:**

**If 1 more document is indexed:**

```
{ "name":"managers" }
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "manage~"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.87546873,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "manage"   
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.7295572,  -->score is different 
                "_source": {
                    "name": "manager"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 0.58364576,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "managers"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**In your case, for `management` you have more than 2 edit distance i.e. `manage` -> `managem` --> `manageme` --> `managemen` --> `management`.
And if the search is made by using a fuzzy query, then their maximum only two edits are allowed .**

**So, therefore, `management` will not match here (by the above search query), rest all words will match (which have edit distance<=2), having different scores.**

Comment: Still, there's no tie between `manager` and `management` they both have the same score and could come back in any order.

Comment: Still, fuzzy matching won't solve the case of the `management` document